# Audio file not playing Python Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to play a audio file using pyglet but I get the error below. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
import pyglet

player = pyglet.media.Player()
sound = pyglet.media.load("air_raid.wav", streaming=False)
player.queue(sound)
player.play()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Christian.wargel/Desktop/audio/audio.py", line 4, in <module>
    sound = pyglet.media.load("air_raid.wav", streaming=False)
  File "C:\Users\Christian.wargel\Documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1431, in load
    source = StaticSource(source)
  File "C:\Users\Christian.wargel\Documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 612, in __init__
    audio_data = source.get_audio_data(buffer_size)
  File "C:\Users\Christian.wargel\Documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\avbin.py", line 426, in get_audio_data
    packet_type, packet = self._process_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Christian.wargel\Documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\avbin.py", line 397, in _process_packet
    audio_data = self._decode_audio_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Christian.wargel\Documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\avbin.py", line 489, in _decode_audio_packet
    duration = float(len(buffer)) / self.audio_format.bytes_per_second
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code works on my laptop with Python 2.7. I guess there maybe something wrong with your .wav sound file. Please check whether your sound file is empty. I downloaded sample14.wav from http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-wav.htm and it really works. Could you test the same sample14.wav file?

Another possible reason may be the the version of your pyglet not matching your python version.